# Merge/Join Files *.001, *.002, *.003.. Without Copying to New One

Tags: windows, file, join

How can I join files into one without copying into new file?
Source: I have file.dd.001, file.dd.002, file.dd.003, file.dd.004 ...
TASK: I have 600 files (1,5 Gb). Capacity of all these files: about 900 GB. HDD capacity: 1,5 TB. I can't join these files with Total Commander or 7-zip, or WinRAR because of HDD capacity of copying into new file (not enough free space).
NEED: Join files, maybe do procedure several times, but:
1) Join 100 first files (150 GB). Delete splitted  files (first 100).
2) Join next 100 files **TO this merged file (150 GB)**. Delete these 100 files.
3) Join next 100 fies to merged file (300 GB)...
Question: can anybody tell me how to make it possible to merge (join) files together TO new bigger and bigger file? Maybe software exists, or last chance to solve this problem with C# code. Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Anony-Mousse with his useful Linux code samples 
Problem has been solved…
Windows has cmd command, which I found in book **Windows Forensic Analysis Dvd Toolkit 2E (2009) by Harlan Harvey** at page. 448:

```
D:\Images>type image.001 >  image_all.img
D:\Images>type image.002 >> image_all.img
D:\Images>type image.002 >> image_all.img
```

If I have file 300 Gb (*image_all.img*), and I need join 50 files (1,5 Gb) to it, I need:

```
D:\Images>type image.200 >> image_all.img
D:\Images>type image.201 >> image_all.img
D:\Images>type image.202 >> image_all.img
D:\Images>type image.203 >> image_all.img
….
D:\Images>type image.498 >> image_all.img
D:\Images>type image.499 >> image_all.img
```

Or, better:

```
D:\Images>type image.* >> image_all.img
```

and it joins all files in folder (with mask) to the file *image_all.img*

Comment: And [here](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=27&tid=968332&pg=-1) some another answers. Maybe, someone wants to see

Answer (score 4):

Write it yourself.

Open file #1. Seek to end. Open file #2, start reading contents and appending to file #1.

When done, delete file #2, and continue with file #3.

Should be < 10 lines in a reasonable scripting language.

I don't know about Windows, but on a unix you could just do:

```
for num in `seq -w 2 600`; do
    cat file.dd.$num >> file.dd.001
    rm file.dd.$num
done
```

Notice the use of the append `>>` output redirection.

You can probably make it faster by using `dd` instead of `cat`, which should use zero-copy transfers (i.e. let the kernel do the work, instead of reading the file into memory and writing it to an output stream).

```
 dd if=file.dd.$num of=file.dd.001 conv=notrunc oflag=append bs=10M
```

This should get you close to whatever your harddisk can provide on IO.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to merge these files to simplify processing, right? If this is your goal, a much more efficient way of doing that is by using FIFO files. On *nix (linux, macos, *bsd, etc) you can create a FIFO file that "represents" all the files, with the mkfifo command as follows:

```
mkfifo mybigfile
cat file.dd.* > mybigfile &
{{process}} mybigfile
```

The file **mybigfile** will contain all the contents of your file.dd.{001,002,003...} files and you can process all these files as a single large file. Once your process completes reading the files, the **mybigfile** will be empty and to "refill" it, you need to execute the "**cat file.dd.* > mybigfile &**" command

Now, the original question contains a number of microsoft windows references (C#, winrar and total commander) so I think that the author needs a windows solution. I'm not a windows guy but I believe the above can be used under cygwin or by using named pipes and PowerShell (but I might be completely wrong)